# Arrange JPanels in top of a ScrollPane, not centered

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jpanelmenu

The following code reproduces my problem as `SSCCE`. I want to create a vertical scrollable list of `JPanels` inside a `JScrollPane`. My actual code aligns the `JPanels` in the center, but it *should be aligned at the top*. 
How can i do this, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestingWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
                frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
                panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);
                scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
                gbc.weightx = 1;

                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

                JPanel panelToAdd = new JPanel();
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Test 1");
                panelToAdd.setBackground(Color.blue);
                panelToAdd.add(label);
                panelToAdd.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
                panel.add(panelToAdd, gbc, -1);
                panel.revalidate();

                JPanel panelToAdd2 = new JPanel();
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Test 2");
                panelToAdd2.setBackground(Color.green);
                panelToAdd2.add(label2);
                panel.add(panelToAdd2, gbc, -1);
                panel.revalidate();

                JPanel panelToAdd3 = new JPanel();
                JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Test 3");
                panelToAdd3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                panelToAdd3.add(label3);
                panel.add(panelToAdd3, gbc, -1);
                panel.revalidate();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Solution based on @MadProgrammer's solution:

Add the following code to create an 'filling' invisible component at the end:

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc_finish = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_finish.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc_finish.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_finish.weighty = 1;
    JPanel panelToAdd4 = new JPanel();
    panelToAdd4.setOpaque(false);
    panel.add(panelToAdd4, gbc_finish, -1);
    panel.revalidate();
```

Comment: You could add a "empty" component to the end and set the associated `gridy` property the `GridBagConstraints` to `1`, this is a little messy if you have a dynamic UI.  You could also consider using the [`VerticalLayout` from the SwingX project](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

Comment: Thanks, the solution including the invisible filler component works fine. I was expecting an Java-Out-of-the-Box solution, so i wasn't thinking in that direction. I posted the working SSCCE above!

Comment: One drawback i noticed: Since the list objects expands, till a scrollbar is shown, you have always a thin "kind of empty"-area at the end. But that would have a very little attendance to the user at all...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing them in the northern panel of your border layout?

```
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: That would just put the scrollpane in the top direction and also it would prevent the scrollpane from filling the fullspace. But i want the panels inside the scrollpane to be top aligned, not the scrollpane itself

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to add a filler `JPanel` at the end of your `panel` with following constraints:

```
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    panel.add(new JPanel(), gridBagConstraints);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @MadProgrammer had this solution posted in a comment before. But the code "gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;" doesn't make sense since its using `REMAINDER` and index  = -1 (in the Component#add(....) method) to create a new row for each added component.